# Plotting words frequency and NLTK

Tags: python, matplotlib, nltk

I have a file with various words, which I want to count the frequency of each word in the document and plot it.
However, my plot is not showing results.
The `x-axis` must contain the words, and the `y-axis` the frequency.
I am using `NLTK`, `NumPy` and `Matplotlib`

Here's my code, maybe I did something wrong

```
def graph():
    f = open("file.txt", "r")
    inputfile = f.read()
    words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(inputfile)
    count = set(words)
    dic = nltk.FreqDist(words)
    FreqDist(f).plot(50, cumulative=False)
    f.close()
```

- Given a list of words in the file `file.txt`:

```
southbound
stopped
travel
lane
started
around
stopped
stopped
started
```

Comment: `FreqDist(f).plot(50, cumulative=False)` you are passing `f` as a parameter in the `FreqDist()` then why are you doing all that processing ? shouldn't you pass `dic` inside the function

Comment: Thank you, finally I was passing the file without proccesing it. Silly me.

Answer (score 14):

```py
import nltk

def graph():
    with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
        inputfile = f.read()
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(inputfile)
    fd = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
    fd.plot(30,cumulative=False)

graph()
```

[image]

You can play with the graph by altering the parameters to the plot()