# dict_keys object has no attribute plot while using nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am using

```
python 3.6(Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32)
```

working on nltk with python3.6, when I am trying to get plot of frequency distribution an error is coming.

Trying below script

```
from nltk.book import *

freq = FreqDist(text5)
freq12 = freq.keys()
freq12.plot(50, cumulative=True)
```

I receive the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    freq12.plot(50, cumulative=True)
AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

How do I get plot while using python 3.6?

Comment: i figured out my mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used the library, but guessing based on [some other question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755861/plotting-words-frequency-and-nltk) I think

```
freq12.plot(50, cumulative=True)
```

should be

```
freq.plot(50, cumulative=True)
```